# Select 7 items with ids centered on id 'n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the set of Foobars with the following ids:

```
1  2  3   5  7   9  11  15  18  19  22 23
```

I need a way to return the Foobars with the following ids, based on ActiveRecord:

```
baz(1) -> 1 2 3 5 7 9 11

baz(9) -> 3 5 7 9 11 15 18

baz(22) -> 9 11 15 18 19 22 23
```

This must be compatible with Ruby on Rails 2.3.9 (no Arel).  It can't be done by simply subtracting and adding 3 from id n, because there may be gaps in the IDs.

edit:  Here's what I did in the end:

```
firstseg = Foobar.all(:conditions => ["id <= " + params[:id]],
    :limit=> 4, :order => "id desc").reverse

@Foobars = firstseg + Foobars.all(:conditions => ["id > " + params[:id]],
    :limit => (7 - firstseg.length).to_s, :order => "id asc")

render 'showthem'
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about what the baz method should do with the argument. Also, does it always use the sorted list of IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo
  def snow_white_and_six_dwarfs
    [ 
      Foo.all(:conditions => ["id < ?", id], :limit => 3, :order => "id ASC"),
      self,
      Foo.all(:conditions => ["id > ?", id], :limit => 3, :order => "id ASC")
    ].flatten
  end
end
```

Now

```
foo.snow_white_and_six_dwarfs
```

OR

```
Foo.find(9).snow_white_and_six_dwarfs
```

Comment: This is great, very close to what I ended up doing (see my edit).

Comment: nice answer (and example!), +1

Answer (score 0):

don't know if there is a better way, but you can do always do something like this:

```
def baz center_id
  all_ids = Foobar.find(:all, :select => "id", :order => "id ASC").collect &:id
  center_index = center_id ? all_ids.index(center_id) : nil

  if center_index
    Foobar.find(all_ids[center_index-3..center_index+3])
  else
    []
  end
end
```

this way, you use the index of the sorted ids instead of the ids themselves. Be careful though, if your center index is less than 3, you will have negative indices, so it will pick ids from the end of the array.

Comment: This solution will bring your DB and web server down if you have few million rows in your `foobar` table. The `all` finders should always be used with a narrow filter or pagination to limit the number of rows returned.

Comment: indeed. your solution is much better.